# Continuous integration, dist folder and node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, continuous-integration

I m actually studying continuous integration and I m actually facing a (little) problem when dealing with the build sequence of the process.

Actually, I have an application that has the following directory at the root of the project:

- src
- doc
- dist
- tests
- node_modules

My question is : when I m at the building step (building the last artifact to put in production, after testing process) should I copy the node_modules directory inside of the dist folder ? So this dist folder could work in standalone (with minification etc... etc...) and so I have only to deploy this folder in my prod environnement ?

How can I move only "dependencies" modules and not "devDependencies" modules ?

Comment: Is this a server-side Node.js application or a client application (just using node_modules as dependencies)?  I am not sure if minification is even necessary for a server-side Node.js application...

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to copy anything, because Node when you `require` a module within your Node app, it will search for `node_modules` in current directory, and if the dependency is not found, it will try to search in its parent and so on.

Check out how Node looks for a package here: http://mycodesmells.com/post/node-basics-looking-for-package/

If you don't want to have development dependencies in your production environment, you can install only non-dev ones:

```
npm install --production
```

Source: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: Or you can prune to production after running the tests: `npm prune --production`

Comment: It's okay, but what If I want to put the less possible file to run my app ? Like only the dist folder ? (the src folder isn't userful at all when my dist folder is built)